# Button is not working when AJAX is using to display data based on drop down menu selection

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a we page (index.html), where user can select option from drop down menu. Based on the selection data will be fetched from database and be displayed on the same page using AJAX (second file is called getParameter.php). Everything works fine. Now I tried to add a Button so that a new page will open and user can edit and send new value to database. But the button press does nothing. I tried it with other html files. It works everywhere else. Any help please

Index.html

```
//AJAX
 <script>

        function showParameterData(str) {
            if (str == "") {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            } else {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET","getParameterData.php?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
</script>



//drop down option selection

<body>

//showParameterData() is the function
<form>
            <select name="Device" onchange="showParameterData(this.value)">
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <option value="1">Device A </option>
              <option value="2">Device B </option>
              <option value="3">Device C </option>
              <option value="4">Device D </option>
              <option value="5">Device E </option>
              <option value="6">Device F </option>
            </select>
            </form>





//bitton to edit and  send data

<div class="edit_button_class" style= "float:right;">
  <form action="edit.html" method="get" target="_blank">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id ="mybutton1" value="Click to Edit" />
  </form>
</div>


<div id="txtHint"></div>

</body>
```

//getParameter.php

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
include ("DBconnect.php");

$conn= mysqli_connect( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db ) or die("Could not connect: " .mysqli_error($conn) );
$sql="SELECT * FROM parameter WHERE ID = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$price = $row['price'];
$version = $row['version'];}

echo '<table>';
echo "<tr>
        <th>Price of the Device :</th>
        <td > $price </td>
</tr>";

echo "<tr>
        <th>version of the Device :</th>
        <td > $version </td>
</tr>";
echo '</table>';
echo '</div>';
```

When I press the button URL is changing to something weird. It is not going to edit.html. Even if I refresh the page, the weird URL is still there. Even though it shows index.html page some extra stuff in the URL

Answer (score 0):

The stuff you are seeing in the URL are get parameters. You by using method='get' you are telling the form to submit in this way.

What this will do is send all the names of the inputs and their values into the URL and "attach" them to the action page you have chosen.

For example, you clicking the button will send you to edit.html with the get parameters of submit and the value of this which is "Click to Edit". Anything that has the name attribute will be sent as a get parameter. You dont need a name for a submit input.

If you place your select into the form with the submit button, it will send the parameter for the select and that means you can use it in your edit page.

```
<div class="edit_button_class">
  <form action="edit.html" method="get" target="_blank">
    <select name="Device" onchange="showParameterData(this.value)">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="1">Device A </option>
      <option value="2">Device B </option>
      <option value="3">Device C </option>
      <option value="4">Device D </option>
      <option value="5">Device E </option>
      <option value="6">Device F </option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id ="mybutton1" value="Click to Edit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

I removed the name from the input as this causes it to be sent as a GET parameter. Using the above you will be sent to /edit.html?submit=Click+to+Edit which you can then use in your edit page to get what you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works. fine Thanks. What if I have two Two drop down List. Lets say List 1- Mechanical Devices.  List 2- Electrical Devices.

I want only one edit button for Two list. In the edit.html  page I wanna give provision to to choose again whether it is Electrical or Mechanical and then Device name.